# Custom UIScrollview embedded in UINavigationView/TableView crashes - on animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

On a UITableView to push to the detail view controller, no matter what I do the `prepareForSegue` can't get the row that was selected. I have tried:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

But that comes up nil. I have tried:

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
```

The thing is that the sender is coming through, as I can see from the log:

```
 Sender is <ARASpecialCell: 0x75cd6d0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 44; 320 44); text = 'Late Night'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x75c98c0>>
```

The special cell was because I tried to subclass the cell and add a public property, but had problems accessing it.

I tried to just get the text label and use that, but produced the error:

```
 "property "textlabel" not found on object of type '__strong id'"
```

I tried "selected row at index path" to load the next view controller, but the detail view controller is set up from another one on the storyboard and it would be a mess to reconfigure.

There is nothing special about this TableViewController. Any suggestions for what's going wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need @property in your controller where you will save selected item. For example, you choose cell and in `didSelectCellAtIndexPath` you save appropriate data object in your selectedItem property. Then you must call segue which you created in interface builder.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     self.selectedItem = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Item Details Segue" sender:self];
}
```

And then in your performSegueWithIdentifier you can do whatever you want with your selectedItem:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"News Details Segue"])
    {
        NewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        NewController.item = self.selectedItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was making at least two mistakes:

Comment: (multiple comments unintentional) 
1) The first, boneheaded mistake, was that I got so hung up in the conflict in pushing the new view controller in `didSelectARowAtIndexPath` that I forgot it was still necessary to call it to get the index path. 

2) Maybe I made mistake 1 because `didSelectARow...` wasn't called because I had the segue hooked up directly to the table view cell. I can see some definite benefits to this, if making an all-custom menu with a table view, it wasn't intuitive. Hooking up to the table fixed it.